# regex: sentence selection

Tags: regex, vim

how do i preserve sentences that start with X criteria and delete sentences that match Y criteria. 
using vim, I would like to delete all sentences that do not start with void.

> void set_first_name(string in_first_name);
>   string first_name();
>   void set_last_name(string in_last_name);
>   string last_name();
>   void set_composer_yob(int in_composer_yob);
>   int composer_yob();
>   void set_composer_genre(string in_composer_genre);
>   string composer_genre();
>   void set_ranking(int in_ranking);
>   int ranking();
>   void set_fact(string in_fact);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vim commands :g and :v help here.

```
:g/regex/action
```

'g' globally selects all lines matching regex and applies the action to them.
'v' inverts the regex (like grep -v), so applies the action to all non-matching lines.

So to delete all lines not starting with void:

```
:v/^void/d
```

where 'd' is the action to delete the line.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a regex for this would look like this:

```
^(?!\s*void).*\n
```

I.e., match the start of the line (`^`), then assert that you can't match `void` here, optionally preceded by whitespace, then match all characters until the following linebreak.

It appears (thanks @Al) that vim supports lookahead via a different syntax (`\@!` for negative, `\@=` for positive lookahead), so this pattern could be transformed into

```
^(\@!\s*void).*\n
```

Comment: If lookaheads are not supported one could use something like `^([^v]|v[^o]|vo[^i]|voi[^d]).*` instead.

Comment: Vim does support lookahead: positive is `\@=` and negative is `\@!`.  So your pattern would be `^\(\s*void\)\@!.*\n` (Vim will deal with the carriage return automatically).